# Delphi / WCF SOAP connectivity and Virtual Machine (VMWare) settings

Tags: wcf, delphi, soap, vmware

I've got a working WCF service and a working Delphi client. On a normal PC, they work nicely. On a VM that's "Bridged" they work nicely if I log onto the domain (but not if I logon locally to the VM as administrator). If the VM is NATed, the connection attempt times out.

I would love to hear people's thoughts on what could be making such a difference to whether the client can successfully connect to the WCF service. Bear in mind I'm connecting with basicHttpBinding with no security.

The service is setup to use System Account (interact with desktop is NOT checked), and it starts automatically. The service URI doesn't change, the port is open, and can be telnet'd to in all scenarios.

Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the VM, open Internet Explorer and verify that you can view the WSDL of the WCF service.  If you can't, then your issue is connectivity and has nothing to do with your Delphi code.

Comment: Thanks Christ, I know the Delphi code is fine, because it works fine on other test environments. The question is more about the quality of the connectivity being dependent on whether you logon to the VM as local admin or a domain account.

Answer (score 0):

Group Policies and Enterprise Security solutions that swap certificates or require certificates to be registered (we're using a UTM called CyberRoam) make a difference.

Also when Virtual Machines join a domain, their ComputerNames are added to a list maintained by the Domain Controller. When the same Virtual Machine is "moved" or "copied", its ComputerName should be changed to avoid DNS resolution issues.

I'm not claiming this as the definitive answer, however it does explain the issues I noticed in this instance.